# Debug Regular expression using RegexBuddy

Tags: regex, regexbuddy

I want to understand how regex parser work so i started debug a string using Regex buddy

also from http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html

Here author explains how Regex engine parser works using following regular expression

```
/cat/
```

and string

```
"He captured a catfish for his cat."
```

author said that if Regex engine didn't find a matching token it backtracks to the last matching character

when i debug this in Regex buddy [see here](http://tinypic.com/r/302z0o0/5) it started backtracking at the very first position

Why is it so ??

Comment: The engine does not know where your match potentially starts, so it checks every single character from left to right as a potential start for the match. This is what the author describes in the first paragraph of section "The Regex-Directed Engine Always Returns the Leftmost Match" on the page you linked.

Answer (score 1):

In RegexBuddy's debugger, the `backtrack` label signifies: "This token has failed to match; now I'm *going to* backtrack.  The next step in the debugger shows what the regex engine actually backtracked to.  In your screen shot there never is a next step after `backtrack` because the regex engine didn't have anything to backtrack to.